# Couchbase FTS Index update through REST API

Tags: couchbase

From latest couchbase doc,Could see FTS index can be created/updated using below
PUT /api/index/{indexName}
Creates/updates an index definition.

I have created index with name fts-idx and created successfully.
But looks like update of index is failing with REST API.

***Response:***
responseMessage : ,{"error":"rest_create_index: error creating index: fts-idx, err: manager_api: cannot create index because an index with the same name already exists: fts-idx"

Anything i have missed here.

Comment: Could you post the body of your REST requests: both the create and the update? I remember running into an issue like this for a blog post I wrote. I think there's a subtle different between create and update requests - https://blog.couchbase.com/powershell-couchbase-rest-api/

Comment: Request details in below link https://gist.github.com/ArihantRk/0b3c77f80a5eb173d39bc4507cc22fa0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate this issue, and I think figured it out. It's not a bug, but it should really be documented better.

You need to pass in the index's UUID as part of the PUT (I think this is a concurrency check). You can get the index's current uuid via `GET /api/index/fts-index` (it's in indexDef->uuid)

And once you have that, make it part of your update PUT body:

```
{
    "name": "fts-index",
    "type": "fulltext-index",
    "params": {
        // ... etc ...
    },
    "sourceType": "couchbase",
    "sourceName": "travel-sample",
    "sourceUUID": "307a1042c094b7314697980312f4b66b",
    "sourceParams": {},
    "planParams": {
        // ... etc ...
    },
    "uuid": "89a125824b012319"    // <--- right here
}
```

Once I did that, the update PUT went through just fine.

Comment: I submitted an issue to the docs here: https://github.com/couchbase/docs-server/issues/205 - if you feel like taking a shot at making the docs clearer for the next person that has this problem, feel free to submit a pull request!